# How can I resize a NSD_SetImageOLE image

Tags: nsis

I'm using the plugin macro `NSD_SetImageOLE` from http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsDialogs_SetImageOLE - And I would like add another macro `NSD_SetStretchedImageOLE` the same way `nsDialog.nsh` works.

But I'm not sure is it's even possible, I've found that the resizing of an `IPicture` can be done by getting the "HBITMAP, BITMAP and BITMAPINFO" and resizing it (quoted from http://www.mofeel.net/958-microsoft-public-vc-mfc/12516.aspx). Anyway, I'm kind of lost trying to covert these methods to NSIS's `System::Call` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
!ifndef IID_IPicture
    !define IID_IPicture {7BF80980-BF32-101A-8BBB-00AA00300CAB}
!endif
!define SRCCOPY 0xCC0020
!include nsDialogs.nsh

!define IMAGEPATH "$sysdir\migwiz\PostMigRes\Web\base_images\Documents.gif" ;"C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\Windows\img0.jpg"
!define NEWSIZEW 200
!define NEWSIZEH 100

Page Custom mypagestretchcreate_GDI ; GDI resize
Page Custom mypagestretchcreate_CTL ; Simple control resize


Function mypagestretchcreate_GDI
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
System::Call 'oleaut32::OleLoadPicturePath(w "${IMAGEPATH}",i0r2,i0,i0,g"${IID_IPicture}",*i.r9)i.r1'
${If} $1 = 0
    System::Call 'user32::GetDC(i0)i.s'
    System::Call 'gdi32::CreateCompatibleDC(iss)i.r1'
    System::Call 'gdi32::CreateCompatibleBitmap(iss,i${NEWSIZEW},i${NEWSIZEH})i.r2'
    System::Call 'user32::ReleaseDC(i0,is)'
    System::Call $9->3(*i.r3)i.r4 ; IPicture->get_Handle
    ${If} $4 = 0
        System::Call 'gdi32::SetStretchBltMode(ir1,i4)'
        System::Call '*(&i40,&i1024)i.r4' ; BITMAP / BITMAPINFO
        System::Call 'gdi32::GetObject(ir3,i24,ir4)'
        System::Call 'gdi32::SelectObject(ir1,ir2)i.s'
        System::Call '*$4(i40,i.r6,i.r7,i0,i,i.s)' ; Grab size and bits-ptr AND init as BITMAPINFOHEADER
        System::Call 'gdi32::GetDIBits(ir1,ir3,i0,i0,i0,ir4,i0)' ; init BITMAPINFOHEADER
        System::Call 'gdi32::GetDIBits(ir1,ir3,i0,i0,i0,ir4,i0)' ; init BITMAPINFO
        System::Call 'gdi32::StretchDIBits(ir1,i0,i0,i${NEWSIZEW},i${NEWSIZEH},i0,i0,ir6,ir7,is,ir4,i0,i${SRCCOPY})'
        System::Call 'gdi32::SelectObject(ir1,is)'
        System::Free $4
    ${EndIf}
    System::Call 'gdi32::DeleteDC(ir1)'
    System::Call $9->2() ; IPicture->release()
${EndIf}
${NSD_CreateBitmap} 1u 1u ${NEWSIZEW} ${NEWSIZEH} ""
Pop $9
;Not required when the control size matches: ${NSD_AddStyle} $9 ${SS_CENTERIMAGE}
SendMessage $9 ${STM_SETIMAGE} ${IMAGE_BITMAP} $2
nsDialogs::Show
System::Call 'gdi32::DeleteObject(ir2)'
FunctionEnd

Function mypagestretchcreate_CTL
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $2
${NSD_CreateBitmap} 0 1u 70% 50% ""
Pop $3
${NSD_AddStyle} $3 ${SS_REALSIZECONTROL}
File "/oname=$PLUGINSDIR\image.bmp" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Header\win.bmp"
${NSD_SetImage} $3 "$PLUGINSDIR\image.bmp" $1
nsDialogs::Show
${NSD_FreeImage} $1
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Is the second call to gdi32::GetDIBits necessary? It doesn't seem to be, but I don't want to break some black magic...

Comment: @hcs Maybe it is for the color table if there is one, I don't really remember.

Comment: Makes sense, the first call gets only a BITMAPINFOHEADER because the previous line cleared biBitCount (the i0 clears biBitCount and biPlanes), then since the bit count is set the second call gets the full BITMAPINFO (including color table), which avoids having to specify a bit count. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have updated http://nsis.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/images/6/65/NsDialogs_setImageOle.zip with a ${NSD_SetStretchedImageOLE} which encapsulates Anders' code for reusability. I've also changed it to use the control dimensions rather than you having to specify the size yourself.